# jQuery unwrap adds a break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery highlight tool which dynamically adds a class to a string. 
If an element contains the word

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

and the user searches for 'ell', it adds a span to the word

```
<p>H<span>ell</span>o world</p>
```

to reset this, I use

```
$("span").contents().unwrap();
```

The problem is in the dom, the text now looks like this

```
<p>H
ell
o World</p>
```

Because jQuery is adding breaks, Searching for 'Hello' wont work.
I have tried removing line breaks and tried css but no luck

```
$('body').html().replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '$1\n');

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just save and restore the initial HTML ?

Comment: The whitespace should make no difference to the layout as HTML ignore it: https://jsfiddle.net/1phn7x4t/1/

Comment: Remember not to use `innerText`, but instead use `textContent`. This will save you some headaches too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because jQuery is adding breaks

No, it is not adding breaks. What you are seeing are simply three separate text nodes. You had three text nodes before, one before and after the span, and one inside – and removing the span has left you with those three separate text nodes.

But there’s an easy way to fix that: [Node.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize)

> *“The `Node.normalize()` method puts the specified node and all of its sub-tree into a "normalized" form. In a normalized sub-tree, no text nodes in the sub-tree are empty and there are no adjacent text nodes.”*

Be aware this is a method of the HTML element object, not the jQuery object – so you need to de-reference a jQuery object before calling this method:

```
$("span").contents().unwrap();
$("p")[0].normalize();
```

Comment: Thanks all, normalize worked for me. Problem solved.